# How to pass two models to one View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass two models into a single view, which are needs to populate a table.

Here I have a requirement to implement this application only using `ASPX` (asp.net-MVC-4). I can do the task using Razor codes but not with ASPX.

I need your kind help to complete the task

Comment: Create a view model containing 2 properties, one for each model.

Comment: Create a ViewModel class with multiple models as properties in it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make one class that contains both models

Your first model:

```
public class ModelOne { ... }
```

Your second model:

```
public class ModelTwo { ... }
```

The model that you pass to your view:

```
public class UltimateViewModel 
{
  public ModelOne One { get; set; }
  public ModelTwo Two { get; set; }
}
```

There is no problem with creating a view model class to encapsulate everything that you want to send to the view. In fact, this would be preferable to doing something like storing one of your models in `ViewState`, since you can enforce your strong typing in the view, referring to everything using `@Model.One` or @Model.Two`.

Comment: Do i need to use Ienumerable here

Comment: If one of your models is an `IENumerable`, then use that instead of my made-up classes.